# android User-space exception detected! java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, exception, post, nullpointerexception

I'm getting this problem here:
creating the ResultadoObject it goes to the catch.

str = "", responseBody = {byte[0]@5870}, while the statusCode: 200

I guess I'm receiving an empty responseBody, any help please? Thank you

```
client.post(url, requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
      System.out.println("onSuccess");
      String str = null;
      try {
          str = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
      }
      catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      if (str != null)
      {
          ResultadoObject resultado = null;
          try {
             resultado = new ResultadoObject(new JSONObject(str));
          } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
          if (resultado.Flag != 0 && resultado.IDMantenimiento != 0)
          {
             loading = false;
             progressDialog.dismiss();
             cambios = true;
             getMantenimiento(resultado.IDMantenimiento);
          }
```

"User-space exception detected!

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.model.ResultadoObject.Flag' on a null object reference
>                                                                    at com.activities.MantenimientoEditarActivity$7.onSuccess(MantenimientoEditarActivity.java:791)
>                                                                    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:351)
>                                                                    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:510)
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)"

Comment: You can show log  result str. i think you miss when parse json.

Comment: str = "", and the responseBody = {byte[0]@5870}, while the statusCode: 200

Comment: you check !=null but you not check ="". Can to use "str.isEmpty():

Comment: Yes, thank you. But the problem is I'm getting an empty responseBody right? Server problem maybe?

Comment: Yes, i think result empty. So it cause null

Comment: so any tip to solve it?

Comment: You can check api response success, after parse data.

Comment: Why have you use retrofit call api

Comment: @QuestionAndroid thank you for your time!